# Spring Boot - configure properties of a jar included as dependency into another jar

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties

I have a Spring Boot web app A and its dependent on a Spring Boot jar library B. I have some properties that I want to configure within B and don't want the client apps (e.g. the web app A) to configure them. I have these properties files in B.

`application-dev.properties`

`application-stage.properties`

`applicatino-live.properties`

The issue is that these properties are not recognized when the library is added as a dependency in web app A. What is the way to achieve this?

Comment: If those are 2 spring boot applications that isn't possible.

Comment: yes they are spring boot applications

Comment: Then it won't work due to the special structure of the Spring Boot fat jar.

Answer (score -1):

The [PropertySource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/PropertySource.html) annotation can be used in a Configuration class on webapp A to achieve what you're looking for:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application-dev.properties"),
@PropertySource("classpath:application-stage.properties"),
@PropertySource("classpath:application-live.properties")
public class WebappAConfiguration {
    
}
```

I also found the order that spring boot looks for externalized configuration helpful [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config).

Comment: Using `spring.profiles.active` like that is a bad idea. It is a `String[]` which can hold multiple profiles, which would then break. Spring Boot will load automatically those files from the classpath if they are present.

Comment: Aah @M.Deinum you're right, I removed that suggestion.